# Define model and form through url dispatcher slug parameters

Tags: python, django, forms, model, django-class-based-views

I have the code in urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from tables.models import subcomponentsTable, rawMaterialsTable
from tables.forms import subcomponentsTableForm, rawMaterialsTableForm

urlpatterns = [path('newEquipment', 
                     views.createTableView.as_view(model=subcomponentsTable,form_class=subcomponentsTableForm), 
                     name='newEquipment'),

              path('newRawMaterial',
                    views.createTableView.as_view(model=rawMaterialsTable, form_class=rawMaterialsTableForm),
                    name='newRawMaterial'), 
              ... etc. ]
```

and i would like to refractor it as follows to make it reusable for different models and forms:

`urlpatterns = [path('new/<slug:tableType>', views.createTableView.as_view(), name='newInstance'),...`

views.py:

```
class createTableView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'tables/createTableTemplate.html'
```

what method in createTableView I should overload, so I could calculate appropriate form and model from slug:tableType, and use it in my view? To do it properly? Will be there any difference with UpdateView and DeleteView?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: A `CreateView` does not care about the slug, since it creates objects, and thus there is no object to update, display, etc.